# Удаляется Temp/2

Tags: windows, windows-10

Временные файлы хранятся в `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2`, но папка 2 регулярно сама удаляется из-за чего приходится ее по новой создавать. В чем может быть дело? Как можно сделать, что бы она не удалялась?

Comment: Компьютер случайно не в домене? А то знавал я такие доменные политики, которые при перезагрузке компа чистили всё что лежит в TEMP. Наверное, это как-то и самому можно где-то выставить, но вы же такое не выставляли сами? Хотя может это фича самой Win10 вообще, я не разбирался.

Comment: ниче не выставлял

Comment: А если создать ещё рандомных папок и файлов? То чё?

Comment: @don Rumata зачем?

Comment: Затем, чтобы понять - удаляется любая папка или где-то прибито гвоздями "регулярно удалять папку "2"".

Comment: Попробую. У меня временные файлы хранятся в папке \Temp\2, возможно ей дан небольшой объем и при переполнении он сам чиститься.

Comment: @don Rumata удалилась папка только 2, создавал папки 3, 4. Они остались

Comment: Ок, тогда в папку "3" напихай мусора на пару гигов ну или сколько у тебя обычно "2" весит.

Comment: да она у меня не успевает весить столько, удаляется раз в 3 дня. Занимает до 500мб максимум. После аварийной перезагрузки сервера и ввода команды echo %temp%, место хранения временных файлов изменилось на /TEMP/3

Comment: Возможно поможет это: http://winlined.ru/articles/Process_Monitor_otslezhivaem_prilozhenie_zapisyvayushchee_neponyatnye_fayly_na_disk.php