# Временные файлы хрянятся в /TEMP/3 как расширить объем хранения данных?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Как можно расширить место под хранение временных файлов в /TEMP/3 на Windows 10? После того, как отрабатывает скрипт, видимо, папка 3 переполняется и удаляется, соответственно при повторном запуске появляется ошибка. Приходиться создавать по-новой папку 3 в `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp` и по-новой запускать программу. Папка удаляется не после каждого запуска, так что дело точно не в программе. Удаляется всегда по-разному, иногда 2 иногда 3 раза подряд отработает, далее удаление...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1158193/398802

Comment: Ну так-то перед запуском скрипта (как и во время его исполнения), ничто не мешает объявить новое значение переменной, указывающей путь хранения временных файлов, - **%TEMP%**

Comment: Можете привести пример?

Comment: set TEMP=d:\Temp

Comment: set TMP=d:\Temp